# Bug when converting image buffer back to base64

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, base64

I am getting a strange bug where, when I convert a base64 string to an image buffer (`Buffer.from(image, "base64")`) and  back to base64 (`.toString("base64")`) the resulting base64 string is missing its formatting (`dataimage/pngbase64` instead of `data:image/png;base64`) as well as missing `g==` at the end. This results in the image being "corrupt" and not rendering when I put it in an `<img />` in the frontend. The current workaround I'm using is the following:

`image.toString("base64").replace("dataimage/pngbase64", "data:image/png;base64,") + "g=="`

but this is far from an optimal solution and I would like to not use this sort of workaround.

This is where I bufferize the image (`image` is base64) and store it in the database

```
t.field("createModel", {
  type: $name,
  args: { input: nonNull(arg({ type: createModelInput.name })) },
  resolve: async (_, args) => {
    const { image, name, manufacturerId, identifiers } = args.input;

    console.log(image) // correct base64 image from frontend
    const buffedImage = Buffer.from(image, "base64");
    console.log(buffedImage.toString("base64")) // not the same as image above: missing formatting & g== at the end

    return await prisma.model.create({
      data: {
        image: buffedImage,
        name,
        identifiers,
        manufacturer: {
          connect: {
            id: manufacturerId,
          },
        },
      },
    });
  },
});
```

Please tell me any further information is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Base64 part of the string doesn't start until after the `,`; the `data:` part is a scheme, the `image/png` part is a content type, and the `base64,` part is an indicator that what **follows** it is Base64 encoded text. So you're asking to convert non-Base64 data when you try to use that entire string as Base64.

You **have** to remove that prefix first, because it's not part of the Base64 data. It's just part of the `data:` URI.